# Echo html that contains php

Tags: php, html

I tried echoing something like:

```
<?php
echo '<div>Example Created to simplify <?php load(somefile.php); ?> </div>';
?>
```

It just displays `Example Created to simplify.`. Is there any way, simple modification of above, with which I can accomplish this.

I of course want to display Example Created to simplify and somefile.php. somefile.php and the text to not cover/block each other.

Comment: We need to know what `somefile.php` contains: code, `echo`, `return`?

Comment: You want the embedded PHP code to execute, so the `somefile.php` is loaded? or you want to actually output `<`, `?`, `p`, etc... as part of the string?

Comment: @MarcB I want to actually load somefile.php. and Jason McCreary somefile.php is a complete html with some php and css as well.

Comment: If you're trying to display the code as an example in your rendered page, then [highlight_file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php) might be useful

Comment: PHP does not recursively parse text. If you want to execute that embedded php snippet, you'll need to structure the code in such a way that PHP sees it as code, e.g. DON'T EMBED IT, or (very bad stupid dangerous idea) use `eval()` which would cause PHP to parse/execute that line as PHP code.

Comment: @MarkBaker, see my comment. It's not so. Precisely, it's a menu. I want to echo menu.

Comment: use include('file.php');

Comment: @Sbml, haha. that was my absent minded error. I intended to write include but wrote load instead. It seems load function is actually there. That won't help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

php is a server-side language. So it makes no sense to send php code to a client browser. Try it like this:

```
<?php
echo '<div>Example Created to simplify '.load(somefile.php).'</div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to open php tag again inside the string. Just use concatenation:

```
<?php
echo '<div>Example Created to simplify' . load(somefile.php) . '</div>';
?>
```

See also: [**PHP: String Operators**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass it through `htmlentities` when you echo it, as the php open tags will appear like HTML tags to the browser and not get rendered. Check the rendered source and you should see it.

```
<?php
echo htmlentities('<div>Example Created to simplify <?php load(somefile.php); ?> </div>');
?>
```

Edit: have I misunderstood the question here? Do you want to echo the line of PHP in line with the markup, or the contents of somefile.php?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
echo '<div>Example Created to simplify' . file_get_contents("somefile.php") . '</div>';
?>
```